# Forecasting in R: UseMethod model function error

Tags: r, forecasting, forecast

I'm trying to run different forecast modeling methods on a monthly tsibble dataset. Its head() looks like:

```
# A tsibble: 6 x 2 [1M]
     month total
     <mth> <dbl>
1 2000 Jan  104.
2 2000 Feb  618.
3 2000 Mar 1005.
4 2000 Apr  523.
5 2000 May 1908.
6 2000 Jun 1062.
```

and has a structure of:

```
tsibble [212 x 2] (S3: tbl_ts/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ month: mth [1:212] 2000 Jan, 2000 Feb, 2000 Mar, 2000 Apr, 2000 May, 2000 Jun, 2000 Jul, 2000 Aug, 2000 Sep, 2000 Oct, 2000 Nov...
 $ total: num [1:212] 104 618 1005 523 1908 ...
 - attr(*, "key")= tibble [1 x 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ .rows: list<int> [1:1] 
  .. ..$ : int [1:212] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  .. ..@ ptype: int(0) 
 - attr(*, "index")= chr "month"
  ..- attr(*, "ordered")= logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "index2")= chr "month"
 - attr(*, "interval")= interval [1:1] 1M
  ..@ .regular: logi TRUE
```

The dataset is monthly from 2000/01 to 2017/08 with no missing values or time periods. I'm trying to run a model such as:

```
df %>%
  model(STL(total ~ season(window=9),robust=T)) %>%
  components() %>% autoplot()

fit <- df %>%
  model(ANN =ETS(total ~ error("A") + trend("A") + season()))
```

But for any type of model I try to run I get the exact same error each time. I'm looking for suggestions to correct the structure of the tsibble to allow these model functions to work.

```
Error in UseMethod("model") : 
  no applicable method for 'model' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_ts', 'tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')"
```

EDIT: Including reproducible example:

```
a = c(sample(1:1000,212))
df.ts <- ts(a, start=c(2000,1),end=c(2017,8),frequency=12)
df <- df.ts %>% as_tsibble()
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @RobHyndman I've updated the question with an example.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with that data set.

Comment: @RobHyndman Just to clarify, are you not getting an error when attempting a model such as `fit <- df %>% model(trend_model = TSLM(value ~ trend()))` , or do you mean that the example still doesn't provide enough to go on?

Comment: I do not get an error using the data generated by that code and then running the code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As both Russ Conte and Rob Hyndman found there's nothing inherently wrong with the example code being used.

I believe there was an overlapping issue between two packages, as my issue was resolved upon removing and reinstalling the forecasting packages.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the example, I was able to get it to run without any errors, as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fpp3)

a = c(sample(1:1000,212))
df.ts <- ts(a, start=c(2000,1),end=c(2017,8),frequency=12)
df <- df.ts %>% as_tsibble()

df %>%
  model(STL(a ~ season(window=9),robust=T)) %>%
  components() %>% autoplot()

fit <- df %>%
  model(ANN =ETS(a ~ error("A") + trend("A") + season()))
report(fit)
```

Here is what the decomposition looks like:

[image]

Here is the report of the model:

[image]